# What is "accessor function"?

Tags: javascript

In [section 4.3.26](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.26) of the Standard ECMA-262 Edition:

> Depending upon the form of the property the value may be represented
>   either directly as a data value (a primitive value, an object, or a
>   function object) or indirectly by a pair of accessor functions.

I didn't understand what "accessor function" means and I didn't find the definition of accessor function in the specification. Then I searched the web. It seemed to me that accessor function means "getter". But I still don't understand, why is the property the value be represented "by a pair of accessor functions"? Can anyone illustrate this with example(s)? Thanks!

Comment: I believe that accessors here mean both getters and setters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"A pair of accessor functions" are the getter and the setter.

[Documentation and example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
var o = {}; // Creates a new object

// Example of an object property added with defineProperty with an accessor property descriptor
var bValue = 38;
Object.defineProperty(o, 'b', {
  get: function() { return bValue; },
  set: function(newValue) { bValue = newValue; },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
```

Comment: What a nice detail that you can define getters and setters for a variable that lives outside of the host object.

Answer (score 5):

An *accessor property* is one that is defined in terms of getters and setters, not as a stored value that might be written to. The "pair of accessor functions" denotes the getter and the setter function.

More information on this can be found in [section §8.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6):

> An Object is a collection of properties. Each property is either a
>   named data property, a named accessor property, or an internal property:
>
> - A named data property associates a name with an ECMAScript language
>     value and a set of Boolean attributes.
> - A named accessor property associates a name with one or two accessor
>     functions, and a set of Boolean attributes. The accessor functions
>     are used to store or retrieve an ECMAScript language value that is
>     associated with the property.
> - An internal property has no name and is not directly accessible via
>     ECMAScript language operators. Internal properties exist purely for
>     specification purposes.

and [Section § 8.6.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.1):

> A named accessor property associates a name with the attributes listed in the following table:
>
> ```
> Attribute| Value     | Description
>  Name    |  Domain   |
> ---------+-----------|---------------------------------------------------------
> [[Get]]  | Object or | If the value is an Object it must be a function Object.
>          | Undefined | The function’s [[Call]] internal method (8.6.2) is
>          |           | called with an empty arguments list to return the
>          |           | property value each time a get access of the property is 
>          |           | performed.
>          |           |
> [[Set]]  | Object or | If the value is an Object it must be a function Object.
>          | Undefined | The function’s [[Call]] internal method (8.6.2) is
>          |           | called with an arguments list containing the assigned
>          |           | value as its sole argument each time a set access of the
>          |           | property is performed. The effect of a property's
>          |           | [[Set]] internal method may, but is not required to,
>          |           | have an effect on the value returned by subsequent calls
>          |           | to the property's [[Get]] internal method.
>          |           |
> [[Enume- | Boolean   | If true, the property is to be enumerated by a for-in
>  rable]] |           | enumeration (see 12.6.4). Otherwise, the property is
>          |           | said to be non-enumerable.
>          |           |
> [[Confi- | Boolean   | If false, attempts to delete the property, change the
> gurable]]|           | property to be a data property, or change its attributes
>          |           | will fail.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A pair of accessor function are referring to [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set). You can indirectly access some value in your object, for example:

```
var person =
{
    get Name()
    {
        return this.name;
    },
    set Name(value)
    {
        this.name = value;
    }
};

person.Name = "X";
console.log(person.Name); // X
```