# Difference between accessor property and data property in ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, accessor

The ECMAScript version 5 specification, introduces a new type of properties called accessor properties. Compared to the existing and known type of properties called data properties, how are these two things related with each other, in terms of specification only?

I've read the spec on ECMAScript v5 and it is not clear to me the exact difference. Can somebody explain the two with a code example? I've searched the internet, but all the examples seem vague.

Comment: Have you even tried to read about it before asking someone here to repeat what the spec says?

Comment: @Touffy Yes i read ecmascript specification, but i still don't understand how can accessor property can hold data without having value attribute and the difference between data property and accessor property.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description

Comment: Just go here and look at the code 
http://jsperf.com/data-vs-accessor-vs-getter-setter/2

Comment: That's the point: it does not hold any data, instead it defines a behavior for when you access the property. Try to use and play with examples to understand better.

Comment: @Touffy But how can private properties(things start their name with _(underscore) can have get and set attributes?

Comment: @beli check my answer. note that _(underscore) does not make your fields private. you must declare your fields with var inside the construtor function, only this way, will your fields be truly private!

Comment: see also [What is an accessor function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26330927/1048572)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A named data property associates a name with a value. Which means you use the property to get and retrieve data directly, like a public field on a class.

A named accessor property associates a name with one or two accessor functions.
The accessor functions are used to store or retrieve a value that is associated with the property. Which means that you restrict the access to a certain value behind a get or/and set accessor property.

Comparing both, the 1st option gives you no encapsulation or kind of control, on how your value is accessed. The 2nd lets you specify if your value can be read 'get accessor', written 'set accessor' or both.

**UPDATE**

Regarding your secondary doubt (in comments) here is a little and quick 101 on the Ecma Script basics that I've just cooked ;):

```
// accounting namespace
var Accounting = {};

// client class definition
Accounting.Client = function(){
    // private fields
    var _address="";
    var _phone=0;

    // data property
    this.token = "";

    // privileged properties
    Object.defineProperty(this, "address", {
        get: function(){
            if(console) console.log('hey im using get address accessor property.');        
            return _address;
        },
        set: function(value){
            if(console) console.log('hey im using set address accessor property.');

            if(value == null)
                throw new Error('Field address cannot be null!');

            _address=value;
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(this, "phone", {
        get: function(){
            if(console) console.log('hey im using get phone accessor property.');
            return _phone;
        },
        set: function(value){
            if(console) console.log('hey im using set phone accessor property.');
            _phone=value;
        }
    });
};

Accounting.Client.prototype = {
    sayHello: function(){
        alert("hello im a shared function, which means im shared by all objects of type Client"
              + " and i do not have access to private fields :(.");
    }
};


/* use case */
var c1 = new Accounting.Client();
c1.address = "Rua da Capela";
c1.phone = 961909090;
c1["token"] = "mytoken in a data property";
c1.token = c1.token + "-111";

alert("client address is '" + c1.address + "' and his phone also is '" + c1.phone + "'.");
c1.sayHello();    
alert(c1.token);

try{
    // check non nullable field.
    c1.address=null;
}
catch(ex){
    alert(ex);
}
```

Use my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qt9rLh2c/2/) to play around!

Happy Coding!